# Adding to list without duplicating publications

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, associative-array

Basically, what I am trying to do is on change of the number input add to a list of publications. The problem being that each time I change the input keeps the previous publication and qty of publications. For example:

I click on the first input 2x and this is what I receive:

publication 1: qty: 1
publication 1: qty: 2

What should happen is when you click on an input it will override the previous qty. So for example:

<strike>publication 1: qty: 1</strike>
publication 1: qty 2
publication 2: qty 1

Notice the strikethrough. that should no longer exist. The qty has been updated.
CODEPEN

http://codepen.io/Jesders88/pen/evVrrw

HTML

```
<input type="number" data-name="something here" data-qty="1" data-id="1">
<input type="number" data-name="something else" data-qty="3" data-id="2">
<input type="number" data-name="something other" data-qty="5" data-id="3">
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
publications = new Array;

$('input').on('change', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var pid = parseInt($(this).data('id')); // id of thing
  var name = $(this).data('name'); // name of thing
  var qty = parseInt($(this).data('qty'));

  console.log(pid);
  console.log(name);
  console.log(qty);

  if(typeof publications[pid] == 'undefined')
  {
     publications[pid] = new Array;
     publications[pid][0] = name;
     publications[pid][1] = qty;
  }
  else
  {
     publications[pid][1] = qty;
  }

  console.log(publications);

  $.each(publications, function(i, l){
    //console.log( "Index #" + i + ": " + l );
    console.log(l[0]+' has a qty of: '+l[1]);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a a couple issues here, most importantly: you are not updating `$(this).data('qty')`, therefore it is always the same value. I personally would use an object instead of an array and just operate on `qty.value` instead of a data attribute that is divorced from the actual value represented in the input:

```
// use an object
var publications = {};

$('input').on('change', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var pid = parseInt($(this).data('id'), 10); // id of thing
  var name = $(this).data('name'); // name of thing
  var qty = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);

  // if you must, set the new quantity into the data property
  $(this).data('qty', qty);

  console.log(pid);
  console.log(name);
  console.log(qty);

  if(!publications[pid])
  {
     publications[pid] = {
       name: name,
       qty: qty
     };
  }
  else
  {
     publications[pid].qty = qty;
  }

  console.log(publications);

  $.each(publications, function(i, l){
    //console.log( "Index #" + i + ": " + l );
    console.log(l.name+' has a qty of: '+l.qty);
  });

});
```

Comment: Awesome. So simple. I can't believe I missed it :). Thank you for your help.